# Pyspark actions submitted with oozie failing: '[Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to submit basic spark actions on YARN to be performed on a hadoop cluster through an oozie workflow, and I get the following error (from the YARN application logs):

```
>>> Invoking Spark class now >>>

python: can't open file '/absolute/local/path/to/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Hadoop Job IDs executed by Spark:

Intercepting System.exit(2)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [2]
```

But I am sure that the file is there. In fact, when I run the following command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /absolute/local/path/to/script.py arg1 arg2
```

it works. I get the output that I want.

Note: I followed everything in this article to get it set up (**I am using Spark2**):
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html

Any ideas?

**workflow.xml** (simplified for clarity)

```
<action name = "action1">
  <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <master>${sparkMaster}</master>
      <mode>${sparkMode}</mode>
      <name>action1</name>
      <jar>${integrate_script}</jar>
      <arg>arg1</arg>
      <arg>arg2</arg>
  </spark>

  <ok to = "end" />
  <error to = "kill_job" />
</action>
```

**job.properties** (simplified for clarity)

```
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${user.name}/${zone}
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
nameNode=hdfs://myNameNode:8020
jobTracker=myJobTracker:8050
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2
sparkMaster=yarn
sparkMode=client
integrate_script=/absolute/local/path/to/script.py
zone=somethingUsefulForMe
```

Exception when running in CLUSTER mode:

```
diagnostics: Application application_1502381591395_1000 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1502381591395_1000_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://hostname:port/cluster/app/application_1502381591395_1000 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://hostname:port/user/oozie/.sparkStaging/application_1502381591395_1000/__spark_conf__.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hostname:port/user/oozie/.sparkStaging/application_1502381591395_1000/__spark_conf__.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$25.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$25.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT2:**

I just tried from the shell, it fails due to an import.

```
/scripts/functions/tools.py
/scripts/functions/__init__.py
/scripts/myScript.py

from functions.tools import *
```

And that's the line it fails at. I'm assuming the script is first copied over to the cluster and run there. How do I get all the required modules to also go with it? Modifying the PYTHONPATH on hdfs? I understand why it's not working just not sure how to fix it.

**EDIT3:**

See stacktrace below. Most of the comments online say the issue is that the python code is setting Master to "local". This is not the case. What's more, I even removed everything spark related (in the python script), and still get the same issue.

```
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://hdfs/path/user/myUser/.sparkStaging/application_1502381591395_1783/pyspark.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hdfs/path/user/myUser/.sparkStaging/application_1502381591395_1783/pyspark.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$25.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$25.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is `/absolute/path/to/script.py` a local filesystem path or HDFS path?

Comment: Good point. It's local. Originally I tried with a HDFS path and got a pretty explicit error that the script must be local. Edited to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the script with oozie, it needs to be placed on HDFS (because you'll never know which node will run the launcher).

After you place it on HDFS, there is need to explicitely tell spark-submit to get it from remote filesystem, so in the job.properties set:

```
integrate_script=hdfs:///absolute/hdfs/path/to/script.py
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. I've already tried this and get the following error:

Error: Only local python files are supported: hdfs:///absolute/hdfs/path/to/script.py.............
Note that I am running in yarn-client mode

Comment: @Tiberiu What versions of oozie and spark do you use? Yarn-client mode shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Oozie 4.2.0, Spark2

Comment: when I was running in cluster mode I was getting a different issue altogether, but I know client works (at least without oozie) because I can run it manually

Comment: Oozie 4.2.0 may be the issue here. It's version from May 2015... I'm pretty sure I used oozie 4.3.0 with "hdfs://" path on input without any problems.

Comment: I just realized that I was wrong - even with4.3.0 you cannot use hdfs path. It's limitation of yarn-client mode (from spark). What issue do you encounter on yarn-cluster?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://path/to/__spark_conf__.zip

Comment: What's weird is that a little higher up in the log I see:

[main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Uploading resource file:/path/to/__spark_conf__7475725353874202876.zip -> hdfs://path/to/__spark_conf__.zip

Without any errors

Comment: Do you have more stack trace lines for FileNotFoundException? I managed to run spark2 job on HDP 2.5.3 (with oozie 4.2.0) and I didn't see issue like this.

Comment: Edited question. Admittedly, I haven't tested too much in cluster mode yet

Comment: But if you run the job using `spark-submit` from shell - does it work? From the log it looks like some impersonation issue. `.sparkStaging` directory should be created in home directory of user that submitted the job to oozie, not the oozie user itself. Do you see any other WARN or ERROR messages in the oozie launcher log?

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks so much for your help. Will keep investigating on my end

Comment: Ok forget my edit. I fixed that part (I had to add the --py-files argument and add all necessary modules needed. Now I'm back to the exact same error as before (as with oozie). The reason .`sparkStaging` was in the oozie user is because I WAS running as the oozie user. Now when I run with another user it fails with the same error, but different home directory.

Comment: Do you have pyspark.zip and py4j*.zip in the sharelib on HDFS?

Comment: I didn't explicitly put them, but in the logs (before the exception) I see:
`17/09/20 02:31:30 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://hostname:port/user/myUser/.sparkStaging/application_1502381591395_1785/pyspark.zip`

Comment: I've boiled it down to a dependency issue. If I don't have any imported modules (that are not already on hdfs), it runs. If I use `--py-files` to send them though, it gives me the error. I'm currently trying to zip them and pass them that way

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** Make sure you don't set `SparkSession.builder.master('something')` in your application code. This must be set in the spark-submit arguments only.

I came across this question by Googling with a similar problem.
My yarn job was failing with an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist` for some file called `__spark_conf__.zip` or `pyspark.zip` on hdfs, in the staging directory.

One of the comments in this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795 helped me understand my mistake.